# Problema al intentar obtener el ultimo id de una tabla con Nodejs y Angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, postgresql

Tengo una tabla en `Postgresql` donde su campo `id(integer)`  no es autoincremental, entonces lo que intento hacer es: **obtener el último id del ultimo registro insertado en la base de datos**. Despues con `Angular` obtener ese id y sumarle uno, para poder insertar un nuevo registro.
Cuando utilizo `Insomnia como cliente REST`, me devuelve el último id. Pero desde `Angular` no obtengo nada.

Aca lo que hice con `Nodejs` desde el `controller.ts`

```js
export const getLastIdCategory = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
    try{
        const response: QueryResult = await pool.query('select max(id_category) from categories');
        return res.status(200).json(response.rows[0]);
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        return res.status(500).json('Internal server error');
    }
}
```

aca el `routes.ts`

```js
router.get('/categories/get/lastId', getLastIdCategory);
```

Aca mi `servicio` en `Angular` para obtener el ultimo id.

```js
getLastId(){
    return this.http.get<any[]>('http://localhost:4000/categories/get/lastId');
  }
```

aca mi `component.ts` de `Angular` donde llamo al `servicio`, pero no obtengo nada.

```js
newId: number;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getLastIdCategory();
  }


getLastIdCategory(){
  this.categoryService.getLastId().subscribe(
    res => {
      // aca obtengo undefined como resultado
      console.log('el id es:' + res[0]);
      this.newId = res[0] + 1;
      // aca obtengo NaN como resultado
      console.log('new id ' + this.newId);
    },
    err => console.error('no se pudo obtener el ultimo id de categria ' + err)
  );
}
```

Comment: en postgresql al hacer el insert podes pedir que [retorne el id](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/dml-returning.html)

Comment: gracias por responder, pero de la forma que lo estoy haciendo, por qué razon no estoy obteniendo el ultimo id desde Angular?

Comment: en principio te diría que es por que el select max no es thread safe, entre el insert y el select algún otro proceso puede haber insertado algo, o aún no haber insertado nada, eso si los nombre de campos y tablas están correctos

Comment: porque ya tengo datos guardados en la tabla

Comment: y no se como hacer de la forma que dices